# Rails alias a text_tag name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there anyway to alias a `text_field` name?

I am using a `form_for` and the model contains two other models, each with similar attribute and method names.

Something like:

```
form_for(@model) do |f|
  f.text_field :name
  f.text_field :name as: :name2
end
```

Comment: Are you referring to a `label_tag`? Have you looked at any of the [Form Helper Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-label_tag)? These are pretty easy to handle. Maybe clarify your question a bit or post some code anything to help us out because right now the question is very vague

Comment: Sorry, I was just leaving work when I asked so was rushed. I have edited the question with more detail and it should have said `text_field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are hoping for is nesting? eg. `model[name]` and `model[sub_model][name]` is that right? If so then you are looking for the `fields_for` method. e.g.

```
<%= form_for(@model) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :sub_model do |sub_fields| %>
    <%= sub_fields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will pass the `sub_model` to a new `FormBuilder` for nesting purposes and will output something long the lines of.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="model[name]" id="model_name" />
  <input type="text" name="model[sub_model][name]" id="model_sub_model_name">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) allows you to use two models inside the same form that have same attribute name. If you want to give the name attribute that's present in both the models a different name (label), you can do that also using an [label_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-label_tag). The code for both the cases is given below for your reference.

```
form_for @modal1 do |f|
   label_tag 'name'
   f.text_field :name

   f.fields_for :modal2 do |t|
     label_tag 'name', 'New name'
     t.text_field :name
   end
end
```

Please comment and give some more details if this is not something you are expecting.